# SXA language embedding

Tags: sxa, multilingual, multisite

I'm working on an `SXA` `multilingual` site, and I've enabled the embed language option, now I can see the `URL` in the navigation has language code + region code

Example:

- mysite/fr-fr/mypage
- mysite/it-it/mypage

But I want to display the URL without the region code

To be like the following :

- mysite/fr/mypage
- mysite/it/mypage

Any idea please?

Comment: For this you need to customize, I don't think it is possible OOTB

Comment: The easiest way to do this is probably to remove the region from the language itself. That way your urls will be correct. Not sure what will happen to existing content however, you might need to write a script to change the language on the existing items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix of this issue

1- create a new patch

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
      <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery" search:require="solr">
        <links>
          <itemUrlBuilder>
            <patch:attribute name="type">Mysite.Foundation.Multisite.Pipelines.NavigationItemUrlBuilder, Mysite.Foundation.Multisite</patch:attribute>
          </itemUrlBuilder>
        </links>
      </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

2- Implement the ItemUrlBuilder

```
public class NavigationItemUrlBuilder : ItemUrlBuilder
    {
        public NavigationItemUrlBuilder(DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions defaultOptions) : base(defaultOptions)
        {
        }

        public override string Build(Item item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
        {
            //enable the Language Embedding for non- english languages 
        options.LanguageEmbedding = item.Language.Name.Equals("en") ? Sitecore.Links.LanguageEmbedding.Never : Sitecore.Links.LanguageEmbedding.Always;
        var RegionName = item.Language.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower() ?? "";
        return item.Language.Name.Equals("en") ? base.Build(item, options) : base.Build(item, options).ToLower().ReplaceFirst(item.Language.Name.ToLower(), RegionName);
        }

    }
```